# display text for a value in a list python3

Tags: list, python-3.x, blackjack

Well i've got 2 lists:

```
deck=[2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11]

symbols=['\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663','\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663','\u2660',          '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663','\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663','\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663','\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663','\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663','\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663']
```

and a function

```
def dealCard(deck,participant):#deal cards , chooses between player and house with string z
  participant.append(deck.pop())
  if z==1:
      print('\nYou got  %s ' %("{} {}".format(player[len(player)-1],symbols.pop()))) 
  else:
      print('\nHouse got %s ' %("{} {}".format(house[len(house)-1],symbols.pop())))`
```

is there any way to display the letter 'A' (stands for ace) instead of 11?

eg.

```
>>>You got A ♡
```

instead of

```
>>>You got 11 ♡
```

Comment: You'll have to use some kind of value to name mapping. `value2name = {11: 'Ace' , ...}` then access it like this `value2name[11]` and it will return `'Ace'`

Comment: if try it out thanks

Comment: Also, `symbols=['\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663'] * 13` , and you might want to add face cards to your deck. Finally, it's easier to do calculations later if you make aces 1, not 11.

Comment: Yeah i should do so !

Answer (score 0):

Use the numbers 1..13 to represent card ranks (A,2,3,...,Q,K). Then use numbers 0..3 to represent suits. Then either make a card object with both of these values or mathematically compose them into an int (I personally like 4 * rank + suit). Using an object would look something like this:

```
def Card(object):
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"][self.rank-1] +
          ['\u2660', '\u2661', '\u2662', '\u2663'][suit]
```

With a **str** function, you'll be able to use print and such.  Build a deck as a list of card objects:

```
deck = []
for rank in range(13):
    for suit in range(4):
        deck.append(Card(rank+1, suit))
random.shuffle(deck)
```

Hands are likewise just a list of cards. Totaling a hand would be like this:

```
def total(hand):
    acefound, soft = False, False
    total = o

    for c in hand:
        if c.rank > 10:
            total += 10
        else:
            total += c.rank
        if c.rank == 1:
            acefound = True

    if acefound and total < 12:
        total += 10
        soft = true

    return total, soft
```